# Cannot find microphone "allow" button in Opera browser

Tags: javascript, browser, speech-recognition, opera

According to [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/), Opera supports the [Speech Recognition API](http://caniuse.com/#feat=speech-recognition). However, when attempting to view a [simple example](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/demos/speech.html), I cannot find the "allow" button alluded to upon click of the microphone icon. In Chrome, the allow microphone dialog immediately pops up when the microphone icon is first clicked.

I'm testing on a clean install of Opera 39/Mac.

[image]

Comment: The Web Speech API is flagged for Opera as `Not supported` on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Speech_API). I'm wondering if the flag in caniuse could be a false positive due to Opera now using the Webkit / Blink Chromium fork also used by Chrome. The example is only  checking if the `webkitSpeechRecognition` object exists to see of the browser is compatible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like HiDeo said, according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechRecognition#Browser_compatibility they do not support webkitSpeechRecognition.

[image]

But the real issue here is that you are not getting prompted to allow the use of your mic. Double check this is correct.

To always allow sites access to your camera and microphone:

1. From the main menu, select Settings.
2. Click Websites on the sidebar.
3. Under Media, select allow sites to access my camera and microphone.

Ultimately, even if you get the mic issue working, you won't be able to use the speechRecognition anyways. If you really want to support Opera (and other browsers), you should think about using IBM bluemix, or Google's new speech to text (in Beta).

Answer (score 2):

That's not how it works in 2019 on the current version; you will not see the options "Websites" which was in old versions.

1. From the main menu, select Settings.
2. Select Privacy and Security
3. Select Content Settings
4. Select Microphone
5. Decide whether to "Ask before accessing".
6. You will have to grant access on the page of the app you are seeking to use the microphone with, i.e. Discord
7. Make sure you haven't blocked that app, i.e. Discord.